# The custom font does not work.Codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, fonts

I want to added custom font in my app, but it does not work.
Here it is path when font located

```
@font-face {    font-family: PF Din Text Cond Pro;
                 src: url('/fonts/JtNLnKEa.ttf'); }
```

font located in `system/fonts/JtNLnKEa`

**UPD**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: PF Din Text Cond Pro;
        src: url('http://contrast-energo.ru/fonts/JtNLnKEa.ttf');
}

body,html { 
  font-family: PF Din Text Cond Pro;
  height: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

How fix?

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

Add your font a directory accessible to your CodeIgniter.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'YourFontName'; /*a name to be used later*/
  src: url('http://domain.com/fonts/JtNLnKEa.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}
```

And use your font name like:

```
.classname {
  font-family: 'YourFontName';
}
```

EDIT:

```
body,html { 
  font-family: "PF Din Text Cond Pro"; /* Add double quotes around your custom font name */
  height: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this solution does work.Update qusetion

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
  font-family:'Lucida Grande';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: url(../fonts/6216.ttf) format('ttf');
}
@font-face {
  font-family:'Myriad Set Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: url(../fonts/myriad.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family:'Helvetica Neue';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: url(../fonts/helvetica-neue-medium.ttf) format('ttf');
}
@font-face {
  font-family:'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: url(../fonts/helvetica-neue-medium.ttf) format('ttf');
}
body
{
    font-family:"Myriad Set Pro","Lucida Grande","Helvetica Neue","Helvetica","Arial","Verdana","sans-serif";
    overflow-x:hidden !important;
}
```

in root folder assets/css/fonts

Answer (score 0):

your appliation structuer should be like this

```
- application
- system
- assets
    - css
    - js
    - fonts
```

etc..

then your access url should be like `http://contrast-energo.ru/assets/fonts/JtNLnKEa.ttf`

Comment: I'm newbie in php/codeigniter.What would it do what I need create 'assets' folder and input here 'css','js' and 'fonts' directory?And all that simple?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't related to CodeIgniter. You have a problem in the CSS/HTML.

You need to use the following CSS code to add properly your fonts to a HTML document:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'PF Din Text Cond Pro';
    src: url('fonts/PF-Din-Text-Cond-Pro.eot');
    src: url('fonts/PF-Din-Text-Cond-Pro.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('fonts/PF-Din-Text-Cond-Pro.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('fonts/PF-Din-Text-Cond-Pro.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The custom font will be displayed on all the browsers.

In case you want to assign the font to the `body` element, you can use the following:

```
body {font-family:'PF Din Text Cond Pro', Arial, sans-serif;}
```

You need to add the font name between single quotes or double quotes, because it's a custom font.

In case you have only a ".otf" or ".ttf" font file, then you need to convert this file to the other formats.

[Online Font Converter](http://onlinefontconverter.com/) is the best **free** font converter out there.

Comment: I do as you say, but nothing change

Comment: Can you check the console ? Check if the CSS was loaded properly. Check if the font file were loaded. If you're using Firebug, have a look at the "Console" tab and the "Net" tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
**Font name has case sensitive**. Use font file name with correct case sensitive. 
My font file name is ***Prata-Regular_0.ttf*** 
So i type this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Prata-Regular_0';
    src: url("http:// YOUR DOMAIN .com/assets/fonts/Prata-Regular_0.ttf"); 

}
```

Not like this:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Prata-Regular_0';
   src: url("http:// YOUR DOMAIN .com/assets/fonts/prata-regular_0.ttf"); 
    
}
```

It works guys...