# how to use custom fonts and icons in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, icons

Slam everyone
i want to use custom icons from flaticon.com inside my view 
the icons in http://successpermis.com/css/flaticon.html
as html it is working fine , but when i use it inside the view it is not working 
i think the problem in loading the font

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon";
    src: url("http://successpermis.com/css/flaticon.eot");
    src: url("http://successpermis.com/css/flaticon.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("http://successpermis.com/css/flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
    url("http://successpermis.com/css/flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("http://successpermis.com/css/flaticon.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

i tried to load fonts from local folders then from online host just like the code above 
can you tell me to do it in a right way

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377927/the-custom-font-does-not-work-codeigniter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

folder structure

```
- application
- assets
    - css 
    - js
    - images
    - fonts
```

style.css

```
  @font-face {
        font-family: "Flaticon";
        src: url("assets/fonts/flaticon.eot");

        -------------
    }
```

Comment: It would be great if you could elaborate a bit about the details, _why_ you think this helps the OP to solve his issue.

Answer (score 0):

```css
  

@font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon";
    src: url("http://successpermis.com/css/flaticon.eot");
    src: url("http://successpermis.com/css/flaticon.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("<?php echo base_url('assets/fonts/flaticon.woff')?>") format("woff"),
    url("<?php echo base_url('assets/fonts/flaticon.tff')?>") format("truetype"),
    url("<?php echo base_url('assets/fonts/flaticon.svg')?>") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.