# custom font url in codeigniter

Tags: css

Hy,
I have a little problem.
I put the font in `assets/fonts/barcode.ttf`
I use the next code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "barcode font";
    src: url(assets/fonts/barcode.ttf) format("truetype");
    src: url(assets/fonts/barcode.svg) format('svg');
    src: url(assets/fonts/barcode.eot);
    src: url(assets/fonts/barcode.woff);
    src: url(assets/fonts/barcode.woff2);
}
.classname {
  font-family: 'barcode font';
}
p.codbare { 
    font-family: 'barcode font';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 80px;
}
```

but is not working. Is not showing the font when I add a text.

Comment: Check if the path is correct, and check if you have the file with .svg, .eot etc etc. It's not a php issue but css correct your tag please

Comment: Remember that those files need to be relative to where you're css file is located. So if your css is under `assets`, then it should be `fonts/barcode.ttf` and so on. Also, as already mentioned, you should _only_ add tags that are directly relevant to your question.

Comment: Check this Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409012/how-to-use-custom-fonts-and-icons-in-codeigniter

Comment: Also, the way your code is written, the browsers can use only the woff2 font. It should have been one `src` property with the values separated by commas.

Comment: The address font is [domain.com/blackboard/assets/fonts/barcode.ttf] with ttf,eot etc... and the file of PHP with CSS is on [domain.com/blackboard/application/views/backend/teacher/tabulation_sheet_print_view.php]. I don't know where I made the mistake.